# Joomla chronoform insert into existing content

Tags: forms, joomla, tinymce

I dont know much about joomla but I have a problem.
I started reading for the chromoform and it is a very nice pugin.
I created a form which I can see in the form manager and also I can view in the url.
but I want ot integrate it to an existing content.

I have a content which contains text, photos etc..
The content is editable with tinymce plugin.
And I want to integrate this form also.

One way to integrate would be to copy the html code and paste in the conent but then if I change the form component the changes would not be also in the conent.

is there a way to include the created form in the content?
Or which is the best one?
Anybody any idea?

Thanx,
Granit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the Chronocontact module (mod_chronocontact), which is provided with ChronoForms. This allows you to insert any ChronoForms form into any module location. The Joomla 1.5 download for this module is [here](http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/chronoforms/chronoforms-j1/87-modules.html).

Then you just need to define a module location in your template, and create a mod_chronocontact module in that location, with your forms name set up. You'll find having a couple of module locations defined immediately before and after your main content in the template is normally handy, like so:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="beforecontent"/>
<jdoc:include type="component" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="aftercontent"/>
```

Comment: Note: I'm not aware of a way to insert a form into the middle of an article - this will only insert the form into the page before or after the article text. Also, I'm assuming Joomla v1.5

Answer (score 1):

If you also have the chrono plugin installed & published, you can add a form into content (such as an article) using the following syntax:
{chronocontact}form_name{/chronocontact}
This allows you to place the form anywhere within the article - you can preface the form with content (such as a heading) ....